# Compile PyQt5 Error: Exe File won't find speech engine?

Tags: compiler-errors, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

when i run this script it works well, but after compiling i cant see any texttospeech engine in combobox list...
The issue is about copyright or something like that? i tried a lot of ways to make an executable file but still same...

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech import QTextToSpeech


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.say)
         
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.engine = None
        engineNames = QTextToSpeech.availableEngines()
        if len(engineNames) > 0:
                engineName = engineNames[0]
                self.engine = QTextToSpeech(engineName)
                self.engine.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)
    
                self.voices = []
    
                for voice in self.engine.availableVoices():
                    self.voices.append(voice)
                    self.comboBox.addItem(voice.name())

        else:
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)


    def say(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.engine.setVoice(self.voices[self.comboBox.currentIndex()])
        self.engine.setVolume(float(self.horizontalSlider.value() / 100))
        self.engine.say(self.lineEdit.text())

    def stateChanged(self, state):
        if(state == QTextToSpeech.State.Ready):
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Read"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select An Available Voice"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Volume"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Read Aloud!"))
```

Comment: you shouldn't be editing .uic files

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with `pyinstaller`. I will first not that you should not edit `pyuic` files.

Since you didn't provide a working example I created a small script which filled in some of the blanks in your code, and was able to get this to work as a single file install.

---

Here are the steps that I took:

OS: Windows

1. create a new directory and cd into directory
2. open new file with name `texttospeech.py` and paste the script below into it
3. `python -m venv venv`
4. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller PyQt5`
5. `pyinstaller -F --noconsole texttospeech.py`
6. edit the `.spec` file so it is the same as the one I included below
7. `pyinstaller texttospeech.spec`
8. all done just run the `texttospeech.exe` in the `dist/` folder

```py
# texttospeech.py

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech import QTextToSpeech


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.say)
        self.central = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.engine = None
        engineNames = QTextToSpeech.availableEngines()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.central.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        if len(engineNames) > 0:
                self.engineName = engineNames[0]
                self.engine = QTextToSpeech(self.engineName)
                self.engine.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)
                self.voices = []
                for voice in self.engine.availableVoices():
                    self.voices.append(voice)
                    self.comboBox.addItem(voice.name())
        else:
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def say(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.engine.setVoice(self.voices[self.comboBox.currentIndex()])
        self.engine.setVolume(float(self.horizontalSlider.value() / 100))
        self.engine.say(self.lineEdit.text())

    def stateChanged(self, state):
        if(state == QTextToSpeech.State.Ready):
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

`.spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
# texttospeech.spec

import os

block_cipher = None

parent = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
modules = os.path.join(parent, "venv", "Lib", "site-packages")
qt5 = os.path.join(modules, "PyQt5")

a = Analysis(
    ['texttospeech.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[(qt5, "PyQt5")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='texttospeech',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that is **pyinstaller** or **cx_Freeze** miss the '**texttospeech**' folder to import when converting to EXE. So you need to copy and paste '**texttospeech**' folder from your created virtual environment path '**env\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins**' to your converted EXE file folder path '**lib\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins**' that it. I do this simple step then it worked for me. If this comment is useful, drop a like.